# Jenkins - How to restrict Jobs and Control Work Flow ?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have **Jenkins** installed Over **Centos 7** OS **.**

I have Three Jobs :

1. One for Build Code **PHP**.
2. One for Build Docker Image and run Docker Container for manual Testing  Using Execute Shell.
3. One for Deploy  Code to Production

What i need is to Restrict Step **Three** that it does not work until Tester mark or Say Step **Two** is good .

Step **Two** runs okay and Run Docker Container and Step **Three** Runs after Step **Two**, but it runs before Tester Say it Is Okay

I am using **Freestyle Project** .

I am using **Post-build Actions**, but i can not control work flow from step **Two** to step **three**

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by Breaking link between step **Two** and step **Three** and link step **Three** by **Slack APP**

1. In Step **Two** in Build Triggers i got " Authentication Token    "
2. In **Slack** add **Slash Command** for example /deploy = jenkinsURL/job/job3//build?token=Token_You_Got_From_Step_Two , and Method **Get**